# Como retornar dados através do CriteriaAPI Java de mais de uma tabela?

Tags: java, java-ee, jpa-2.0, criteria

Tenho uma classe que nao persiste:

PessoaDadosSearch.java

```
public class PessoaDadosSearch{

    private Long idPessoaDadosSearch;
    private String nome;
    private String cpf;
    private String municipioResidente;

    //getters e setters implementados

}
```

E as classes que persiste no banco:

Pessoa.java

```
@Entity
public class Pessoa{

   private Long idPessoa;
   private String nome;

   //getters e setters

}
```

Documento.java

```
@Entity
public class Documento{

    private Long idDocumento;
    private String tipoDocumento;
    private String numeroDocumento;
    //getters e setters

}
```

Municipio.java

```
@Entity
public class Municipio{

   private Long idMunicipio;
   private String nomeMunicipio;
   //getters e setters

}
```

e PessoaDadosSearchDAO.java

```
public class PessoaDadosSearchDAO{

   //Outras implementações

   public List<PessoaDadosSearch> retornaPessoaDadosSearch(String nomePessoaAPesquisar, String cpfAPesquisar){
       List<PessoaDadosSearch> result = new ArrayList<PessoaDadosSearch>();

       // *COMO IMPLEMENTAR O CRITERIA API PARA ME RETORNAR A LISTA DE OBJETOS PessoaDadosSearch AQUI?*

       return result;
   }

}
```

Como ficaria a implementação para me retornar a lista de objecto PessoaDadosSearch na DAO?

Answer (score 0):

Considerando,

- `em` = instância do EntityManager.
- `"municipio"` = o nome da coluna de relacionamento entre `Pessoa` e `Municipio` na classe `Pessoa`;
- `"documento"` = o nome da coluna de relacionamento entre `Pessoa` e `Documento` na classe `Pessoa`;

```java
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<PessoaDadosSearch> criteria = builder.createQuery(PessoaDadosSearch.class);
Root<Pessoa> root = criteria.from(Pessoa.class);
Join<Pessoa, Municipio> mun = root.join("municipio");
Join<Pessoa, Documento> doc = root.join("documento");
criteria.select(builder.construct(PessoaDadosSearch.class, p.get("idPessoa"),      
p.get("nome"), mun.get("municipioResidente"));
List<Predicate> predicados = new ArrayList<>();
predicados.add(builder.equal(p.get("nome"), nomePessoaAPesquisar));
predicados.add(builder.equal(doc.get("numeroDocumento"), cpfAPesquisar)); 
criteria.where(predicados.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
result = em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
```